# Why entity cannot be found if I did detach after persist

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have Stateless Session Bean with Container-Managed Transactions. I want to return unmanaged entity after create (persist) it in a database. That's how I do it:

```java
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

   @EJB(name="MyController")
   private MyController myController;

   public MyEntity create(MyEntity entity) {
      //...
      myController.create(entity);
      myController.preTransfer(entity);
      return entity;
   }
}
```

```java
@Stateless
public class MyController {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
   private EntityManager em;

   public void create(MyEntity entity) {
      //...
      em.persist(entity);
   }

   public void preTransfer(MyEntity entity) {
       if (em.contains(entity)) {
           em.detach(entity);
       }
       //...
   }
}
```

I call *MyBean.create*, entity successfully persisted and *MyBean.create* return unmanaged entity, that's ok. But next time when I try retrieve this entity by id, it can't be found. If I comment *detach*, entity can be found, but *MyBean.create* return managed entity in that case. Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of [`EntityManager.detach`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) states:

> Unflushed changes made to the entity if any (including removal of the
>   entity), will not be synchronized to the database

So you're persisting it, then detaching it. But the operations associated to persist have not been flushed yet, and the entity is thus not saved to the database.

Why do you want to detach it? As soon as the transaction is ended, it will be detached automatically.

Comment: I need to detach entity, because I need to set some fields of entity before return it from business method

Comment: Sounds like you want to return a data transfer object instead of the entity. Why would you return an entity which doesn't represent the state in the DB?

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen Introducing DTO just for the purpose of getting a detached entity is a really bad idea, unless it's EJB 2.1 or older (but it isn't here). Why do you think entities are serializable?

Comment: I agree with Tuukka. Either it's an entity, and it should represent persistent state, or it should be a DTO. Non persistent fields in entities can be used (even if it's ugly, IMHO), but they must be marked with @Transient.

Comment: @MaDa It sounds like he wants to create an entity and return the entity instance with some fields changed (having different state than what's in the DB). Didn't say (or at least mean) anything about serialization?

Comment: @tuuka-mustonen was right, I want to change some fields before return.

Answer (score 0):

Amending JB's answer: you could as well use clean, standard mechanism, without forcing the container to detach or flush explicitly:

```
@Stateless
public class MyController {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public MyEntity create(MyEntity entity) {
       //...
       em.persist(entity);
       return entity;
    }
}
```

You'll get a detached entity as a result.

Comment: ok, this will work in that case. But JPA not supports nested transactions that's why this will not work in more complicated cases.
For example, I want to create any other entities, works with them in unmanaged state, and all of it in the same transaction.